# cant remove, reinstall or anything of that sort for linux-firmware /lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg

Tags: virtualization, intel

some tries and errors, the thing is this is also a vps, i would just like to switch to linux-image-virtual or what ever its called anyway, but i would also just like to be able to upgrade my software atm

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-firmware
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  distro-info libevdev2 libimobiledevice6 libplist3 libupower-glib3 libusbmuxd6
  linux-headers-5.4.0-73 linux-headers-5.4.0-73-generic upower usbmuxd
The following packages will be upgraded:
  alsa-ucm-conf apport erlang-asn1 erlang-base erlang-crypto erlang-dev erlang-diameter
  erlang-edoc erlang-eldap erlang-erl-docgen erlang-eunit erlang-ic erlang-inets erlang-inviso
  erlang-mnesia erlang-nox erlang-odbc erlang-os-mon erlang-parsetools erlang-percept
  erlang-public-key erlang-runtime-tools erlang-snmp erlang-ssh erlang-ssl erlang-syntax-tools
  erlang-tools erlang-xmerl intel-microcode libasound2 libasound2-data libmysqlclient21
  libnetplan0 libpq5 libunbound8 libxmlb1 linux-headers-generic linux-libc-dev netplan.io
  open-iscsi postgresql-13 postgresql-client-13 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common
  python3-apport python3-problem-report python3-update-manager python3-yaml thermald tmux
  ubuntu-advantage-tools update-manager-core
52 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
43 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/61.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 467 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 137369 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-firmware (1.187.10) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg/sof-tgl-rt711-rt1308.tplg.dpkg-new': Bad message
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-firmware
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
43 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 559 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 137369 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-firmware (1.187.10) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg/sof-tgl-rt711-rt1308.tplg.dpkg-new': Bad message
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

sudo apt --fix-missing reinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-firmware
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
43 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 559 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 137369 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-firmware (1.187.10) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg/sof-tgl-rt711-rt1308.tplg.dpkg-new': Bad message
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.187.12_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package linux-firmware.
(Reading database ... 137370 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_1.187.12_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.187.12) over (1.187.10) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.187.12_all.deb (--install):
 unable to stat './lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg/sof-apl-asrc-wm8804.tplg' (which I was about to install): Bad message
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.187.12_all.deb
```

Comment: so nobody can help me on this ehh

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the filesystem was corrupted

Fixed it by booting from ubuntu install cd and doing fsck, surprised their busy box doesnt contain fsck and cryptsetup